# simplest way to permit end user edit one table with a grid?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have one table (could be more in future) in database and want to user edit the values in this table.  (without access to SQL studio.)

I was trying excel - but it is possible by SSIS which is not immediate or needs programing. SQL 2016 permit to use excel files as external table but i have previous version of SQL.

In MS Access i remember was possible to connect to sql server, just create form and insert grid to edit. But Access cost.

So are there any free solution just give possibility to edit values in one table from server?

Comment: you can execute SQL statements to update tables via SSIS and Powerquery for example but the user would need write permissions on that table. But what it sounds like you are describing is some kind of linked table where edits in Excel are reflected in the associated SQL table?

Comment: This appears to be what you are describing https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10392.editing-an-sql-server-table-in-excel

Comment: unforutnatelly this solution don't permit add rows. "For similar reasons, currently the implementation doesn't allow adding new rows to the table."

Comment: Apologies, I missed the add rows requirement and "assumed" updates were involved :-(